# Unspecified GSS failure, No Kerberos credentials available

Tags: ssh

I tried to ssh to a server and get this error:
"Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more information No Kerberos credentials available"

I am not exactly sure what it means. (Still try to Google it)

```
; ssh -vT -p 1234 root@mysite.com
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to mysite.com [1.2.3.4] port 1234.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/kenpeter/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/kenpeter/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kenpeter/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kenpeter/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kenpeter/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kenpeter/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kenpeter/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kenpeter/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA xxxxx....xxxxxx....
debug1: Host '[mysite.com]:1234' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/kenpeter/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/kenpeter/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kenpeter/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kenpeter/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kenpeter/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@mysite.com's password:
```

When I type my password, I get "permission denied".

Answer (score 0):

The remote server did allow root remote access, but the password was changed and it is different from the documentation I have.